# How to paint the petals?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I can make the drawing but I don't paint the dark region.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
\draw[thick](0,0)--(4,0);
\draw[thick](4,0)--(4,4);
\draw[thick](4,4)--(0,4);
\draw[thick](0,4)--(0,0);
\draw[thick](4,0)--(0,4);
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0) arc (-90:90:2cm);
\draw[ultra thick] (0,4) arc (-180:0:2cm);
\node at (-0.3,0) {D};
\node at (-0.3,4) {A};
\node at (4.3,0) {C};
\node at (4,4.3) {B};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Gonzalo, Show! I should have thought of this before....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is based on [Gonzalo Medina's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251404/). If you use the `even odd rule` for the filling, you can avoid the need for manually clipping and scoping things (but see below). You can also make the code more compact by integrating the labels with the drawing commands. Whether any of this is an advantage is another question. But that it is, at least, an alternative, seems undeniable.

Note that the only reason two paths are needed is that some lines are drawn with `thick` and some with `ultra thick`. Otherwise, the code could be reduced to a single path.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
    \path [fill=gray!60, draw, thick, even odd rule] (4,4) node [above right] {B} rectangle (0,0) node [below left] {D} arc (-90:90:2cm) arc (-180:0:2cm) -| (0,0) node [midway, above left] {A} (4,0) node [below right] {C} -- (0,4);
    \draw[ultra thick] (0,4) arc (-180:0:2cm) (0,0) arc (-90:90:2cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: fillings without clipping]

However, the `ultra thick` curve looks rather untidy to me where it meets the lines at A, B and D. It looks as if the curve is spilling out of the square. Here, the easiest solution seems to be clipping the `ultra thick` lines. (So, I recommend clipping after all, but you can do it just once for the thickly drawn curve after everything else is drawn and filled.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
    \path [fill=gray!60, draw, thick, even odd rule] (4,4) node [above right] {B} rectangle (0,0) node [below left] {D} arc (-90:90:2cm) arc (-180:0:2cm) -| (0,0) node [midway, above left] {A} (4,0) node [below right] {C} -- (0,4);
    \clip  (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
    \draw[ultra thick] (0,4) arc (-180:0:2cm) (0,0) arc (-90:90:2cm);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: clipped thick curve]

Comment: Cfr, This method serves to paint the region between three mutually tangents circles?

Comment: @benedito Er... does it? I don't know what 'mutually tangents circles' are so, if it does, that is entirely fortuitous. (Or not, depending on whether that's a good thing or a bad thing.)

Answer (score 4):

Clipping and filling:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.2]
\begin{scope}
\clip (0,0) arc (-90:90:2cm);
\clip (0,4) arc (-180:0:2cm);
\fill[gray!60] (0,0) rectangle (4,4);
\end{scope}
\fill[gray!60] (0,0) arc (-90:0:2cm) arc (-90:0:2cm) -- (4,0) -- (0,0);
\draw[thick] (4,0) -- (0,4) -- (0,0) -- (4,0) -- (4,4) -- (0,4) -- (0,0);
\draw[ultra thick] (0,0) arc (-90:90:2cm);
\draw[ultra thick] (0,4) arc (-180:0:2cm);
\node[below left] at (0,0) {D};
\node[above left] at (0,4) {A};
\node[below right] at (4,0) {C};
\node[above right] at (4,4) {B};
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

A also changed the way the labels were positioned and made some other change to the way the square is drawn, but thst's not essential for the answer.

Comment: Sorry. I think I stole your tick :(.

Comment: @cfr Don't be sorry! I don't mind when a tick goes to a better ansswer.

Comment: You are very nice but it seems unfair when I started from yours!